# Get rows with same primary key with different status in reference table

Tags: mysql

I'm having following table

```
id task_id stage_id is_completed
1   1         1        1
2   1         2        1
3   1         3        0
4   2         1        1
5   2         2        0
6   2         3        1
7   3         1        1
8   3         2        1
9   3         3        0
```

How can I get all task_ids where stage_id = 1 and is_completed = 1 and stage_id = 2 and is_completed = 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SELECT * from mt_task_status 
where 
task_id in ( SELECT task_id FROM mt_task_status WHERE stage_id = '1' and is_completed = '1')
and task_id in ( SELECT task_id FROM mt_task_status WHERE stage_id = '2' and is_completed = '0')
and stage_id in (1,2)
order by task_id

Answer (score 1):

You can use the combinations of `AND` and `OR`, e.g.:

```
SELECT task_id
FROM tasks
WHERE (stage_id = 1 AND is_completed = 1)
OR (stage_id = 2 AND is_completed = 2)
GROUP BY task_id;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but what I need is task_ids where stage_id = 1 must be completed and stage_id = 2 is not completed. Not either of one

Comment: yeah, but I need only those corresponding task_ids where both condition satisfied E.g. from my table I should get only task_id 2, others where completed in both stage. Only task_id 2 is (stage 1 completed and stage 2 not completed)

Answer (score 0):

Use `union`:

```
select task_id from table where stage_id = 1 and is_completed = 1
union
select task_id from table where stage_id = 2 and is_completed = 0
```